# Styling of Custom Plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a simple contact form plugin manually and I want to style it without inline styling. I also made a css file style.css for its styling but it doesn't worked for me. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working for you? Please provide mockup or sample code to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to style backend (admin side) then you can use wp_enqueue_style .
check below code . Add this code in your plugin page.

```
define('PLUGIN_URL', plugins_url('', __FILE__ ) . '/');

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','my_plgin_style' );

function my_plgin_style(){
wp_enqueue_style('pluginstyle', PLUGIN_URL .'style.css');
}
```